# Lettrine doesn't care of lower size

Tags: lettrine

I'm currently using `lettrine` package and when I set a lower size bigger than zero it seems doesn't work.

This is my tex source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,italian,a4]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lettrine[lines=4,loversize=0.9]{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ullamcorper, magna sed commodo suscipit, massa eros ultrices nisl, quis iaculis metus tortor quis est. In eu pulvinar erat. Nullam scelerisque scelerisque mi eget lobortis. In malesuada gravida magna, non ultrices orci luctus ac. Aenean ornare tempus ligula. Sed pharetra tempus leo quis aliquam. Aliquam luctus sollicitudin mi, quis auctor quam accumsan quis. Sed at nisl quis est commodo auctor. Suspendisse eget odio vitae justo gravida bibendum et eget turpis. Suspendisse porttitor commodo blandit. Vivamus quis mi turpis. Vivamus iaculis tincidunt dignissim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
\end{document}
```

These are the warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size <78.02933> not available
(Font)              size <35.83> substituted on input line 12.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size <94.90416> not available
(Font)              size <35.83> substituted on input line 12.

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 59.07416pt have occurred.
```

And this is the output PDF in which the L is not scaled correctly:
[image]

Comment: Load the `fix-cm` package.

Answer (score 7):

Use some nice font that can be scaled -- for example `kpfonts` or `lmodern`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,italian]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lettrine[lines=4,loversize=0.9]{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ullamcorper, magna sed commodo suscipit, massa eros ultrices nisl, quis iaculis metus tortor quis est. In eu pulvinar erat. Nullam scelerisque scelerisque mi eget lobortis. In malesuada gravida magna, non ultrices orci luctus ac. Aenean ornare tempus ligula. Sed pharetra tempus leo quis aliquam. Aliquam luctus sollicitudin mi, quis auctor quam accumsan quis. Sed at nisl quis est commodo auctor. Suspendisse eget odio vitae justo gravida bibendum et eget turpis. Suspendisse porttitor commodo blandit. Vivamus quis mi turpis. Vivamus iaculis tincidunt dignissim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this font include math symbols?

Comment: @tyranitar Do you mean math fonts? yes, `kpfonts` and `lmodern` will change math font also.

Comment: @HarishKumar try with "lines=2" only (no loversizing). Will look much better. Also `\usepackage[latin]{babel}` for better hyphenation of "lipsum text."

Comment: @YiannisLazarides My likes too. But the OP is after `loversize` `:-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar ...sure, but it hit me on the eye!